Upgrade to Ubuntu LTS24.04 External Harddrive not mounting
I have upgraded to the new version of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS since the upgrade I cannot access my Ext Hard drive which holds all my files {as a security protection).
Error mounting dev/sub1 at/media/john/File storage`1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sub1, missing codepage or helper programme, or other error.
my external hard drive that has ALL my files on it! What can I do?

dev/sub1 is that a typo? should it be sdb1 and what format is the external HD. [edit] in to your question along with the result of lsblk in terminal. If it is NTFS look at and review this Stack Exchange post

sorry - yes  dev/sdb1

seagate Fast SSD 1TB    NTFS

This question is similar to: NTFS filesystem on external drive isn't recognised: "mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
